# 2DimentionnalArray Out of Range with Go

Tags: matrix, go, slice

i try to build a two dimensionnal array. My code compile but fail on execution with this error :

```
Create Matrice with heigth of 10 and width of 10
Area length  = 10, Area cap = 10
Loop 0
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3
Loop 4
Loop 5
Loop 6
Loop 7
Loop 8
Loop 9
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

This is my code, The method create, build a array of array like the go doc show.  :

```
// matrice project matrice.go
package matrice

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TwoDimensionnalMatrice struct {
    col, row int
    area     [][]int
}

func (m TwoDimensionnalMatrice) Create(x, y int) {
    m.col = x
    m.row = y
    fmt.Printf("Create Matrice with heigth of %d and width of %d\n", x, y)
    m.area = make([][]int, m.col)
    fmt.Printf("Area length  = %d, Area cap = %d\n", len(m.area), cap(m.area))
    for i := range m.area {
        fmt.Printf("Loop %d\n", i)
        m.area[i] = make([]int, m.row, m.row)
    }
}

func (m TwoDimensionnalMatrice) Get(row, col int) int {
    return m.area[row][col]
}
```

and the code that call it :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "matrice"
)

func main() {
    mat := matrice.TwoDimensionnalMatrice{}
    mat.Create(10, 10)
    fmt.Printf("%d", mat.Get(5, 5))
}
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/tKoZ9HuLLd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver for `Create()` is a value instead of a pointer which means you're mutating a copy of `mat` in your main function rather than `mat` itself.

Change:

```
func (m TwoDimensionnalMatrice) Create(x, y int)
```

to:

```
func (m *TwoDimensionnalMatrice) Create(x, y int)
```

Or more likely, you want a function in `matrice` that returns a new matrix rather than initialising an existing one:

```
func New(x, y int) (*TwoDimensionnalMatrice, error) {
   ... create a matrix, initialize it, then return it.
}
```

Comment: Thx for this rapid answer